# How to fill gaps between each segment of the 7-segment character

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I want to recognize digits from odometer by mobile using tesseract library.
Source image:

[image]

Next step:

[image]

Now i need to fill gaps between each segment. 
Can you help me, how i do it?
(english training data work better for me than https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr)

```
image processing: 

func prepareImage(sourceImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let avgLuminanceThresholdFilter = GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter()
    avgLuminanceThresholdFilter.thresholdMultiplier = 0.67

    let adaptiveThresholdFilter = GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter()
    adaptiveThresholdFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 0.67

    let unsharpMaskFilter = GPUImageUnsharpMaskFilter()
    unsharpMaskFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 4.0

    let stillImageFilter = GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter()
    stillImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 1.0

    let contrastFilter = GPUImageContrastFilter()
    contrastFilter.contrast = 0.75

    let brightnessFilter = GPUImageBrightnessFilter()
    brightnessFilter.brightness = -0.25

    //unsharpen
    var processingImage = unsharpMaskFilter.imageByFilteringImage(sourceImage)

    processingImage = contrastFilter.imageByFilteringImage(processingImage)
    processingImage = brightnessFilter.imageByFilteringImage(processingImage)

    //convert to binary black/white pixels
    processingImage = avgLuminanceThresholdFilter.imageByFilteringImage(processingImage)

    return processingImage

  }
```

OCR:

```
let tesseract_eng = G8Tesseract()
    tesseract_eng.language = "eng"
    tesseract_eng.engineMode = .TesseractOnly
    tesseract_eng.pageSegmentationMode = .Auto
    tesseract_eng.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0
    tesseract_eng.setVariableValue("0123456789", forKey: "tessedit_char_whitelist")
    tesseract_eng.image = prepareImage(image)
    tesseract_eng.recognize()
```

Comment: After you fill the gaps, display_ocr will work better for your task. See [this](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr/blob/master/OCR.py#L213) for a sample code of using OpenCV erode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has some morphology methods, which white fill the gaps between black pixels (like [THIS](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) or [THIS](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphological-operations)). Pay attention to morphology opening method, this should be the primary method for solving this, but do not be afraid to combine it with dilating if only this does not help. I am not sure what software do you use for image processing, if it does have similar methods, try them out, otherwise I would highly recomend you installing OpenCV, which (is free of course) has many image-processing operations with very high speed. Also, you could try a bit to experiment with threshold values and find the balance between how much corners it cuts out and how much shadows it takes off (combined with morphological operations this should solve the issue for you).